# drawRect is not called when the view is appeared again

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I was using `drawRect` like `viewWillAppear` and check some states and set some values to labels.

It was ok on **iOS 12 and later**. But, `drawRect` is not being called is **iOS 11.3 and earlier**.

So, I found a workaround. I'm using `willMoveToWindow` method to do somethings that I'd do in `viewWillAppear`

```
   @implementation AFEBigLapTimerWidgetView
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        if (self.viewModel.isLapTimerServiceStarted) {
            [self setLapTimerButtoStateWithState:AFELapimerButtonStateLap];
            [self.viewsToHide enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *_Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                obj.hidden = NO;
            }];
            [self.viewModel updateLabelsForStartedService];
        } else if (self.viewModel.isCountdownOngoing) {
            // Check if countdown is ongoing
            self.countdownLabel.hidden = NO;
            self.countdownLabel.alpha = 1.0;
            [self setLapTimerButtoStateWithState:AFELapimerButtonStateLap];
            [self countdownValueChanged:self.viewModel.countdownValue];
            [self.viewsToHide enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *_Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                obj.hidden = YES;
            }];
        } else {
            [self setupDefaults];
        }
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Please post some code that shows what you are doing.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't abuse `drawRect` like this. If you can tell use what you are trying to achieve, we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: I have a custom view in menu. When I go inside a detail view, I can change somethings. And when I go back, I want that view to be refreshed, set some other values to the labels. I'll put the code.